# How do I disable notifications/reminder and set events to free time with Perl's ICal::Entry?

Tags: perl, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Unforunately my university was too lazy to make a google calendar or `.ics` for our public events. Instead they choose to wirte us an email with a formatted text file containing a list of the dates. I have a Perl script to convert said list, into an iCalendar (`.ics`) file. I want to import that `.ics` into my google calendar later.

So far the script works very well but now I want to **disable the standard notifications (E-Mail and PopUp)** and **set the events to be free time (instead of default busy)**. The problem is, that I don't get anything usefull out of  the documentation for [Data::ICal::Entry::FreeBusy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-ICal/lib/Data/ICal/Entry/FreeBusy.pm) and [Data::ICal::Entry::Alarm::Display](http://search.cpan.org/~alexmv/Data-ICal/lib/Data/ICal/Entry/Alarm/Display.pm). Be so kind an provide me with the right properties to add to the `$event->add_properties(...)` line in the script below:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Converts a specially formated text file (list of events) into an .ics
# (iCalendar) file for import into Google-Calendar or other calendar
# applications.

use Date::ICal;
use Data::ICal;
use Data::ICal::Entry::Event;

# Read file into one long string
open FILE, $ARGV[0] or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
my $fstring = join("", <FILE>);
close FILE;

# Prepare calendar
my $calendar = Data::ICal->new();
$calendar->add_properties( method=>"PUBLISH",);

# Add events depending on what was found in file
my @events = split("\n\n", $fstring);
foreach $eventstring (@events) {
    my $eventstring =~ s/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)//; # remove date from the string
    my $datestring = $1;                    #+but save it for processing:
    ($day, $month, $year) = split(/\./, $datestring);
    $title = ( split /\n/, $eventstring )[1]; # what is left is the title

    my $event = Data::ICal::Entry::Event->new();
    $event->add_properties(
        summary     => "Kolloquium: $title",
        description => $eventstring,          #+and the long description
        dtstart     => Date::ICal->new( year=>"20$year", month=>$month, day=>$day, hour=>17, min=>15 )->ical,
        dtend       => Date::ICal->new( year=>"20$year", month=>$month, day=>$day, hour=>18, min=>15 )->ical,
        dtstamp     => Date::ICal->new( epoch => time )->ical,
        # MISSING HERE: Right FREEBUSY and ALARM properties. PLEASE HELP!
    );
    $calendar->add_entry($event);
}

print $calendar->as_string;
```

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all some general remarks:

1. add `use strict;`
2. add `my` in the loop `foreach my $eventstring (@events) {` and remove it from below line `my $eventstring =~ s/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)//;`
3. as a good practice, try to avoid the bareword `FILE` and define the filehandle as a scalar variable `open my $FILE,$ARGV[0]`

So now, to answer your question, import those 2 modules...

```
use Data::ICal::Entry::FreeBusy;
use Data::ICal::Entry::Alarm::Display;
```

...and I believe you have to add the following to your code:

```
my $event = Data::ICal::Entry::Event->new();
$event->add_properties(
    summary     => "Kolloquium: $title",
    description => $eventstring,          #+and the long description
    dtstart     => Date::ICal->new( year=>"20$year", month=>$month, day=>$day, hour=>17, min=>15 )->ical,
    dtend       => Date::ICal->new( year=>"20$year", month=>$month, day=>$day, hour=>18, min=>15 )->ical,
    dtstamp     => Date::ICal->new( epoch => time )->ical,
);
my $vfreebusy = Data::ICal::Entry::FreeBusy->new();
$vfreebusy->add_properties(
    organizer => 'MAILTO:jsmith@host.com',
    freebusy   => Date::ICal->new( epoch => ... )->ical . '/' . Date::ICal->new( epoch => ... )->ical, #don't forget to define the time!
);
my $valarm = Data::ICal::Entry::Alarm::Display->new();
$valarm->add_properties(
    description => "Wake up!",
    trigger   => [ Date::ICal->new( epoch => ... )->ical, { value => 'DATE-TIME' } ], #don't forget to define the time!
);

$calendar->add_entry($valarm);
$calendar->add_entry($vfreebusy);
$calendar->add_entry($event);
```

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't that SET an alarm and mark me as busy instead of disabling the default alarm that google would impose? And same for busy time instead of wanted free?

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad! So who sets the default alarm? The results of `print $calendar->as_string;` are OK, no default alarm there. If it is the Google Calendar, then did you checked its settings if there is a default value there. If there's nothing to do from the application side, then maybe you must create the alarm as shown above, but with a date in the past and see how it will be imported in GC.

Comment: Yes google creates the default alarm if none is specified. I though there was an explicit "no reminder"-property in the ICal standard or something.

Comment: I quickly checked the iCalendar file format [RFC5545](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545) and didn't found any "no reminder" properties. So it seems to be purely the fault of the Google Calendar web application. Try to change the settings of GC as described [here](http://superuser.com/questions/173717/getting-google-calendar-to-set-no-reminders-by-default) before importing, and let us know if that worked.

Comment: Okay thanks, I hoped for some explicit no reminders. Guess I'll just have to change gCalendars settings every time I add an `.ics`. I did not find a "mark the events as free time by default" option in either Google or iCal. Infuriating.